# Using VPC Endpoint for DynamoDB with Amazon.DynamoDBv2

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-net

I have a .Net core app hosted on Elastic beanstalk currently using DynamoDB with `AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2` package and from what i understand, connection to dynamodb will happen over public internet unless i use the dynamodb vpc gateway endpoint.

How can i specific the vpc endpoint while using `AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2` package ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code runs in the VPC with the endpoint, you don't need to do anything.

The VPC endpoint will "overwrite" the DNS name of the public endpoint and redirect the traffic to it over a private connection.

Comment: the overwrite will happen automatically ?.Does this apply to all gateway endpoint ?

Comment: S3 and DynamoDB (which are the only gateway endpoints) behave this way, yes. The same is true for the interface endpoint, although the technology behind them is different. All of that assumes that you don't mess with the DNS-settings in the VPC.